# Unnesting tibble columns: "Wide" data summaries with dplyr v1.0.0

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'd like to produce "wide" summary tables of data in this sort of format:

```
                                   ----   Centiles  ----
Param    Group   Mean       SD      25%     50%      75%
Height       1   x.xx    x.xxx     x.xx    x.xx     x.xx
             2   x.xx    x.xxx     x.xx    x.xx     x.xx
             3   x.xx    x.xxx     x.xx    x.xx     x.xx
Weight       1   x.xx    x.xxx     x.xx    x.xx     x.xx
             2   x.xx    x.xxx     x.xx    x.xx     x.xx
             3   x.xx    x.xxx     x.xx    x.xx     x.xx
```

I can do that in dplyr 0.8.x.  I can do it generically, with a function that can handle arbitrary grouping variables with arbitrary numbers of levels and arbitrary statistics summarising arbitrary numbers of variables with arbitrary names.  I get that level of flexibility by making my data [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html).  That's not what this question is about.

First, some toy data:

```r
set.seed(123456)

toy <- tibble(
         Group=rep(1:3, each=5),
         Height=1.65 + rnorm(15, 0, 0.1),
         Weight= 75 + rnorm(15, 0, 10)
       ) %>% 
       pivot_longer(
         values_to="Value", 
         names_to="Parameter",
         cols=c(Height, Weight)
       )
```

Now, a simple summary function, and a helper:

```r
quibble2 <- function(x, q = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)) {
  tibble(Value := quantile(x, q), "Quantile" := q)
}

mySummary <- function(data, ...) {
  data %>% 
    group_by(Parameter, Group) %>% 
    summarise(..., .groups="drop")
}
```

So I can say things like

```r
summary <- mySummary(toy, Q=quibble2(Value), Mean=mean(Value, na.rm=TRUE), SD=sd(Value, na.rm=TRUE))
summary %>% head()
```

Giving

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  Parameter Group Q$Value $Quantile  Mean     SD
  <chr>     <int>   <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Height        1    1.45      0.25  1.54 0.141 
2 Height        1    1.49      0.5   1.54 0.141 
3 Height        1    1.59      0.75  1.54 0.141 
4 Height        2    1.64      0.25  1.66 0.0649
5 Height        2    1.68      0.5   1.66 0.0649
6 Height        2    1.68      0.75  1.66 0.0649
```

So that's the summary I need, but it's in long format.  And `Q` is a `df-col`.  It's a tibble:

```r
is_tibble(summary$Q)
[1] TRUE
```

So `pivot_wider` doesn't seem to work.  I can use `nest_by()` to get to a one-row-per-group format:

```r
toySummary <- summary %>% nest_by(Group, Mean, SD)
toySummary
# Rowwise:  Group, Mean, SD
  Group  Mean      SD               data
  <int> <dbl>   <dbl> <list<tbl_df[,2]>>
1     1  1.54  0.141             [3 × 2]
2     1 78.8  10.2               [3 × 2]
3     2  1.66  0.0649            [3 × 2]
4     2 82.9   9.09              [3 × 2]
5     3  1.63  0.100             [3 × 2]
6     3 71.0  10.8               [3 × 2]
```

But now the format of the centiles is even more complicated:

```r
> toySummary$data[1]
<list_of<
  tbl_df<
    Parameter: character
    Q        : 
      tbl_df<
        Value   : double
        Quantile: double
      >
  >
>[1]>
[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Parameter Q$Value $Quantile
  <chr>       <dbl>     <dbl>
1 Height       1.45      0.25
2 Height       1.49      0.5 
3 Height       1.59      0.75
```

It looks like a `list`, so I guess some form of `lapply` would probably work, but is there a neater, tidy, solution that I've not spotted yet?  I've discovered several new verbs that I didn't know abou whilst researching this question (`chop`, `pack`, `rowwise()`, `nest_by` and such) but none seem to give me what I want: ideally, a `tibble` with 6 rows (defined by unique `Group` and `Parameter` combinations) and columns for `Mean`, `SD`, `Q25`, `Q50` and `Q75`.

To clarify in response to the first two proposed answers: getting the exact numbers that my toy example generates is less important than finding a *generic technique* for moving from the `df-col`(s) that `summarise` returns in `dplyr` v1.0.0 to a wide data summary of the general form that my example illustrates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**revised answer**

Here is my revised answer. This time, I rewrote your `quibble2` function with `enframe` and `pivot_wider` so that it returns a `tibble` with three rows.

This will again lead to a `df-col` in your `summary` `tibble`, and now we can use `unpack` directly, without using `pivot_wider` to get the expected outcome.

This should generalize on centiles etc. as well.

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123456)

toy <- tibble(
  Group=rep(1:3, each=5),
  Height=1.65 + rnorm(15, 0, 0.1),
  Weight= 75 + rnorm(15, 0, 10)
) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    values_to="Value", 
    names_to="Parameter",
    cols=c(Height, Weight)
  )

quibble2 <- function(x, q = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)) {
  pivot_wider(enframe(quantile(x, q)),
              names_from = name,
              values_from = value) 
}

mySummary <- function(data, ...) {
  data %>% 
    group_by(Parameter, Group) %>% 
    summarise(..., .groups="drop")
}

summary <- mySummary(toy, Q=quibble2(Value), Mean=mean(Value, na.rm=TRUE), SD=sd(Value, na.rm=TRUE))

summary %>% 
  unpack(Q)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 7
#>   Parameter Group `25%` `50%` `75%`  Mean    SD
#>   <chr>     <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Height        1  1.62  1.66  1.73  1.70 0.108
#> 2 Height        2  1.73  1.77  1.78  1.76 0.105
#> 3 Height        3  1.55  1.64  1.76  1.65 0.109
#> 4 Weight        1 75.6  80.6  84.3  80.0  9.05 
#> 5 Weight        2 75.4  76.9  79.6  77.4  7.27 
#> 6 Weight        3 70.7  75.2  82.0  76.3  6.94
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**Second approach**
without changing `quibble2`, we would need to first call `unpack` and then  `pivot_wider`. This should scale as well.

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123456)

toy <- tibble(
  Group=rep(1:3, each=5),
  Height=1.65 + rnorm(15, 0, 0.1),
  Weight= 75 + rnorm(15, 0, 10)
) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    values_to="Value", 
    names_to="Parameter",
    cols=c(Height, Weight)
  )

quibble2 <- function(x, q = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)) {
  tibble(Value := quantile(x, q), "Quantile" := q)
}

mySummary <- function(data, ...) {
  data %>% 
    group_by(Parameter, Group) %>% 
    summarise(..., .groups="drop")
}

summary <- mySummary(toy, Q=quibble2(Value), Mean=mean(Value, na.rm=TRUE), SD=sd(Value, na.rm=TRUE))

summary %>% 
  unpack(Q) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Quantile, values_from = Value)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 7
#>   Parameter Group  Mean    SD `0.25` `0.5` `0.75`
#>   <chr>     <int> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 Height        1  1.70 0.108   1.62  1.66   1.73
#> 2 Height        2  1.76 0.105   1.73  1.77   1.78
#> 3 Height        3  1.65 0.109   1.55  1.64   1.76
#> 4 Weight        1 80.0  9.05   75.6  80.6   84.3 
#> 5 Weight        2 77.4  7.27   75.4  76.9   79.6 
#> 6 Weight        3 76.3  6.94   70.7  75.2   82.0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**generalized approach**

I tried to figure out a more general approach by rewriting the `mySummary` function. Now it will convert automatically those outputs to `df-cols` which return a vector or a named vector. It will also wrap `list` automatically around expressions if necessary.

Then, I defined a function `widen` which will widen the `df` as much as possible, by preserving rows, including calling `broom::tidy` on supported `list-columns`.

The approach is not perfect, and could be extended by including `unnest_wider` in the `widen` function.

Note, that I changed the grouping in the example to be able to use `t.test` as another example output.

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123456)

toy <- tibble(
  Group=rep(1:3, each=5),
  Height=1.65 + rnorm(15, 0, 0.1),
  Weight= 75 + rnorm(15, 0, 10)
) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    values_to="Value", 
    names_to="Parameter",
    cols=c(Height, Weight)
  )

# modified summary function
mySummary <- function(data, ...) {

  fns <- rlang::enquos(...)

  fns <- map(fns, function(x) {

    res <- rlang::eval_tidy(x, data = data)

    if ( ((is.vector(res)  || is.factor(res)) && length(res) == 1) ||
         ("list" %in% class(res) && is.list(res)) ||
           rlang::call_name(rlang::quo_get_expr(x)) == "list") {
      x
    }
    else if ((is.vector(res)  || is.factor(res)) && length(res) > 1) {
      x_expr <- as.character(list(rlang::quo_get_expr(x)))
      x_expr <- paste0(
        "pivot_wider(enframe(",
        x_expr,
        "), names_from = name, values_from = value)"
      )
      x <- rlang::quo_set_expr(x, str2lang(x_expr))

      x
    } else {
      x_expr <- as.character(list(rlang::quo_get_expr(x)))
      x_expr <- paste0("list(", x_expr,")")
      x <- rlang::quo_set_expr(x, str2lang(x_expr))

      x
    }
  })

  data %>% 
    group_by(Parameter) %>%
    summarise(!!! fns, .groups="drop")
}


# A function to automatically widen the df as much as possible while preserving rows
widen <- function(df) {

  df_cols <- names(df)[map_lgl(df, is.data.frame)]
  df <- unpack(df, all_of(df_cols), names_sep = "_")

  try_tidy <- function(x) {
    tryCatch({
      broom::tidy(x)
    }, error = function(e) {
      x
    })
  }

  df <- df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(across(where(is.list), try_tidy))
  ungroup(df)
}

# if you want to specify function arguments for convenience use purrr::partial
quantile3 <- partial(quantile, x = , q = c(.25, .5, .75))

summary <- mySummary(toy,
                     Q = quantile3(Value),
                     R = range(Value),
                     T_test = t.test(Value),
                     Mean = mean(Value, na.rm=TRUE),
                     SD = sd(Value, na.rm=TRUE)
)

summary 
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   Parameter Q$`0%` $`25%` $`50%` $`75%` $`100%` R$`1`  $`2` T_test   Mean    SD
#>   <chr>      <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <list>  <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Height      1.54   1.62   1.73   1.77    1.90  1.54  1.90 <htest>  1.70 0.109
#> 2 Weight     67.5   72.9   76.9   83.2    91.7  67.5  91.7  <htest> 77.9  7.40

widen(summary)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 11
#>   Parameter `Q_0%` `Q_25%` `Q_50%` `Q_75%` `Q_100%`   R_1   R_2 T_test$estimate
#>   <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>           <dbl>
#> 1 Height      1.54    1.62    1.73    1.77     1.90  1.54  1.90            1.70
#> 2 Weight     67.5    72.9    76.9    83.2     91.7  67.5  91.7            77.9 
#> # … with 9 more variables: $statistic <dbl>, $p.value <dbl>, $parameter <dbl>,
#> #   $conf.low <dbl>, $conf.high <dbl>, $method <chr>, $alternative <chr>,
#> #   Mean <dbl>, SD <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-14 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  But unless I'm missing something, this simply returns the tibble to the state it was in durectly after calculating the summary.  That is, it's long rather than wide.

Comment: From your comment to the answers above I thought you were "more interested in the technique for handling the new df-cols than in getting these numbers out from this specific example", so I focused my answer on converting the `df-cols` to normal columns, but I assume that still is not the heart of your issue. Do you want a generic function that handels any kind of summary function and converts its output to columns? But then I do not quite understand how the `df-cols` fit in, avoiding them by using lists - as suggested above - seems a better approach.

Comment: I now revised my answer and came up with a rather flexible approach, at the price of rewriting `quibble2`, so I am not sure if this is an option for you.

Comment: I just noticed, that there is no need to rewrite `quibble2`.

Comment: Thanks Tim.  Both your efforts look pretty good.  Apologies if I wasn't clear in my description.  The issue is that my code needs to be generic (ie handle any function that returns multiple values and `quibble2` (and equivalents) - which need to be provided by end users - need to be as simple as possible.  I can consult and decide which option is most acceptable.

Comment: What other functions do you habe in mind. I might have an idea, but would it would be good to know what kind of functions you expect.

Comment: In the real use case, the functions could be any statistical summaries of a (large) sample of a random variable.  So I think `quantile` is likely to be the most complicated case, but other summary functions could return multiple values: `range` for example.  The input dataset will be a tidied version of output from an MCMC analysis.  An `mcmc.list` object from `run.jags` for example.  So the perfect solution would behave sensibly with multiple `df-col` columns, each of different lengths - three quantiles from `quantile` and min and max from `range` for instance.  Thanks for your interest.

Comment: I came up with a first draft of a generalized version. Please have a look.

Comment: "Now it will convert automatically those outputs to df-cols which return a vector or a named vector".  That's where I was heading myself.  At first glance, your generalised approach is exactly what I wanted, but in a much neater form than I would have managed.  No solution is ever going to be perfect, but you've certainly widened (pun intended) the cases that can be handled, and also hidden the complexity inside the summary function, which is ideal.  Thank you.  If I could upvote again, I would.

Answer (score 0):

What if you change `quibble2` to return a list, and then use `unnest_wider`?

```
quibble2 <- function(x, q = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)) {
  list(quantile(x, q))
}
mySummary(toy, Q=quibble2(Value), Mean=mean(Value, na.rm=TRUE), SD=sd(Value, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
  unnest_wider(Q)
# A tibble: 6 x 7
  Parameter Group `25%` `50%` `75%`  Mean    SD
  <chr>     <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Height        1  1.62  1.66  1.73  1.70 0.108
2 Height        2  1.73  1.77  1.78  1.76 0.105
3 Height        3  1.55  1.64  1.76  1.65 0.109
4 Weight        1 75.6  80.6  84.3  80.0  9.05 
5 Weight        2 75.4  76.9  79.6  77.4  7.27 
6 Weight        3 70.7  75.2  82.0  76.3  6.94
```

Comment: That's a fair shout Alan, but I'm more interested in the *technique* for handling the new `df-cols` than in getting these numbers out from this specific example.  I think the `df-col`s have advantages over list cols - try printing the tibbles from each of our `quibble2` functions for example.  `unnest_wider` is new to me though.  That deserves a look.  I wonder if there's a `chop` or `unpack' equivalent?

Comment: As a bit of feedback, I don't see how anyone could have guessed that you were specifically interested in unnesting tibble columns from the title or content of your question.

Comment: Thank you, Ian.  I was editting the question as you replied and have also amended the title as a result of your comment.  I hope you think the changes clarify what I'm looking for.

Comment: Good luck finding an answer, if I have a bit of time, I may think about it some more.