# R wrap function call into another call without using string manipulation

Tags: r, function, call, rlang

I'm looking for a nice way to wrap a function call into another function call. Wrapping a function before it is being called into other functions is easy, but modifying an existing call seems not so straight forward to me.

I found a way which I explain using the example below, but it is basically relying on converting the call into a list into a string, then adding the new call as string and convert everything back to language using `str2lang`.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Lets assume I'm building a custom `summarise` function for `dplyr` which will check, whether the output is a vector and in that case create a `df-col` by using `pivot_wider(enframe(...))` on the existing call.

Here is the reprex.

```r
library(tidyverse)

short_sum <- function(data, ...) {

  fns <- rlang::enquos(...)

  fns <- purrr::map(fns, function(x) {

    res <- rlang::eval_tidy(x, data = data)

    if ((is.vector(res)  || is.factor(res)) && length(res) > 1) {

      # is there a better way to do this (start) ---
      # get expression of call and turn it into a string
      x_expr <- as.character(list(rlang::quo_get_expr(x)))

      # construct a string with expression above wrapped in another call
      x_expr <- paste0(
        "pivot_wider(enframe(",
        x_expr,
        "), names_from = name, values_from = value)"
      )

      # turn string into language and replace expression in x
      x <- rlang::quo_set_expr(x, str2lang(x_expr))
      # is there a better way to do this (end) ---

      x
    } else {
      x
    }
  })

    dplyr::summarise(data, !!! fns, .groups="drop")
}


mtcars %>% 
  as_tibble %>% 
  short_sum(quant = quantile(mpg),
            range = range(wt))

#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   quant$`0%` $`25%` $`50%` $`75%` $`100%` range$`1`  $`2`
#>        <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1       10.4   15.4   19.2   22.8    33.9      1.51  5.42
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

This question is based on my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62353857/9349302) where I use the approach above.

Comment: As I started to read, I found myself thinking "This sounds familiar..." :)

Comment: There are a couple of occasions where I use a similar approach, but I think it should be avoided to construct and modify calls from strings. Your question is a good example for this more general question about modifying function calls in R. Let’s see if there are better approaches.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you want to achieve? The code you’ve posted is nontrivial and contains parts that don’t seem to pertain directly to the question. Are you looking simply for `bquote(outer_call(.(inner_call_expr)))`?

Comment: I tried to keep the code minimal, but still with a real and working example, where the expression I want to modify is actually evaluated. At the heart of the issue is that I want to change the expression in the quoted call `x` without converting it to a string and then wrapping this string with `paste` into a longer string which is then turned into language again. This seems unnecessarily verbose and clumsy to me. I also added enclosing comments around the part I want to improve. How would you rewrite this using `bquote`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what the function does but I think you might be looking for something like this :

```
short_sum <- function(data, ...) {

  fns <- rlang::enquos(...)

  fns <- purrr::map(fns, function(x) {
    res <- rlang::eval_tidy(x, data = data)

    if ((is.vector(res)  || is.factor(res)) && length(res) > 1) {
      rlang::expr(pivot_wider(enframe(
        !!rlang::quo_get_expr(x)), names_from = name, values_from = value))
      # or
      # bquote(pivot_wider(enframe(
      #  .(rlang::quo_get_expr(x))), names_from = name, values_from = value))
    } else {
      x
    }
  })

  dplyr::summarise(data, !!! fns, .groups="drop")
}
```

`expr()` is like `quote()`, except you can use `!!` or `!!!` to unquote parts of the expression.

`bquote()` is like `quote()` as well, but in base R, and you use `.()` to unquote.

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for. I used your approach and added it to `x <- rlang::quo_set_expr(x, rlang::expr(pivot_wider(enframe(!! rlang::quo_get_expr(x)), names_from = name, values_from = value)))` so that the result is not a `call` but a `quosure` which also keeps to environment. In the end the trick was to evaluate `!! rlang::quo_get_expr(x))` and wrap it inside `expr`.